# Using the powr.io countdown plugin

Tags: views, javascript

So I am trying to use the powr.io countdown plugin and it says I should simply have to paste their  tag and  tag into the body of a Drupal body field and it should work. But it is only spitting out the code as plain text though I am using WYSIWYG text format which shouldn't filter anything. Any suggestions? thank you

Comment: Don't use a Text format.

Answer (score 1):

As Beebee mentioned, "don't use Text format" I ended up changing my body field to plain text editor and this allowed it to work.